# Are where any examples available on how to use postcss-modules instead of css-modules?

Tags: css, webpack, postcss, css-modules

CSS Modules support built into `webpack` looks pretty simple: you just `require`/`import` CSS file and webpack generate code that do two things:

- Injects generated CSS into your webpage
- Returns you a dictionary of classnames to use.

And the usage is pretty simple too:

```
import styles from "./style.css";
element.innerHTML = '<div class="' + styles.className + '">';
```

I want to test alternative CSS Modules implementation, a `PostCSS` plugin - since it seems to play well with other `PostCSS` plugins, especially `autoprefixer`. But according to official [documentation](https://github.com/outpunk/postcss-modules) it seems that `postcss-modules` works very differently compared to `webpack` CSS Modules. Where are no usage exaples in documentation and only some callback code that generates `JSON`. Any examples how it's used in practice to achieve same goal as sample code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of the plugin. I'm rewriting it right now and right after that I'll write the example.

In the callback, you can save the JSON object with the classes' description and read it into your code. You should read the JSON file, not the CSS:

```
import styles from "./style.css.json";
element.innerHTML = '<div class="' + styles.className + '">';
```

Comment: thanks a lot! But in order for webpack to run loader that will convert `css` into `json`, this `css` file need to be specified somewhere? So i need to `import` both `css` to generate `json` and `css`, and after that `import` `json` to get names, is this correct?

Comment: In your case, it is better to use CSS Loader, you can use any PostCSS plugins with it. 

`postcss-modules` is created for server-side rendering in mind. But if you want to use it with webpack you have to build your CSS with another tool, like Gulp. Or you can use Webpack only but you have to build CSS before JS somehow.

Comment: When should you import pcss files inside a pcss file and when should you use require in a js file?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [following](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/master/tools/webpack.config.js) usage of post-css plugin. They are not using post-css as a replacement for the css-loader but instead as a complement to it.

If you have a look at line 99. They create post-css function which is called as first loader.The example given is for scss but you can change it to css. After preprocessing the css in this case they call other loaders.

Comment: This question is about postcss-modules, not about how to use postcss with css-loader.